# Show that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}d\zeta = k_1+k_2$, with order of zero $k_1, k_2$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, roots, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ a domain and $D=D_1(0)\subset\subset G$. Let $f: G\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic and has two roots $z_1, z_2$ with order of zero $k_1, k_2 >0$. For $z\neq z_1, z_2$ let $f(z)\neq 0$. Prove this equation: $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}d\zeta = k_1+k_2$$

I'm really stucked with this task. I can see a similarity to the Cauchy Integral formula. And I know that a antiderivative of this function is $\log(f(\zeta))$. But I don't know how to get a good proof. Any hints or help? Thank you!

Comment: Could you do it if there were only one zero (so that you could deform the path to a circle around that zero)?

Comment: No not really, sorry! The most problem for me is to get the coherence beetween the order of zeros and this integral.

Comment: Around $z_m$, write $f(z) = (z - z_m)^{k_m}\cdot g_m(z)$ with $g_m$ holomorphic and $g_m(z_m) \neq 0$. Use that to compute the residue of $f'/f$ at $z_m$.

Comment: Why one can write this for $f(z)$? And unfortunately we didn't learned the residue theorem.

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

Comment: @rtybase Yeah I looked at that, but how I said I've never learned the residue theorem in the lecture.

Comment: Write $f(z) = (z-z_1)^{k_1} (z-z_2)^{k_2} g(z)$, where $g(z) \ne 0$ in $G$.

Comment: @MartinR: I've tried to solve the integral with this. I get: $$k_1k_2\int\limits_{\partial D} \frac{1}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}+log_{(-\pi)}(g(z))+c(z)$$ I can't see how to go on or if it's correc till this point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $z_1, z_2$ are the only zeros of $f$,
$$
 f(z) = (z-z_1)^{k_1} (z-z_2)^{k_2} g(z)
$$
for some holomorphic function $g: G \to \Bbb C$ which has no zeros in $G$.
It follows that
$$
 \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{k_1}{z - z_1} + \frac{k_2}{z - z_2}
+ \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}d\zeta
= \frac{k_1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z_1}
+ \frac{k_2}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z_2}
+ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{g'(\zeta)}{g(\zeta)}d\zeta
\, .
$$
The last integral is zero because $g'/g$ is holomorphic in $D$,
and the other two can be computed easily.